# Creating a file in a specific directory using Bash?

Tags: file, bash, directory

Normally to create a file in a directory I would use:

```
echo > /home/user/fileName
```

but, in this case, my directory path I want to create the file in is stored in a variable in my script so I can't write out the path like that. How do I create a new file inside of it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a variable `myPath`, you can use:

```bash
echo > "${myPath}/fileName"
```

as per the following transcript:

```bash
pax:~$ export myPath="/tmp"

pax:~$ ls -al /tmp/xyzzy
ls: cannot access /tmp/xyzzy: No such file or directory

pax:~$ echo > "${myPath}/xyzzy"

pax:~$ ls -al /tmp/xyzzy
-rw-r--r-- 1 pax pax 1 2011-12-06 12:30 /tmp/xyzzy
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```
echo > ${WHATEVER}/fileName
```

Answer (score -1):

Won't something like

```
touch $variable/filename
```

work?

Answer (score -1):

```
 #Enter designated directory

 cd designatedDirectory

 #Create file in directory

 cat > file.txt

 #OR

 touch file.txt
```